# How configure or intercept next-auth with Prisma?

Tags: prisma, next-auth

I'm letting users login with GitHub following the [official guide](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma) for next-auth / Prisma and it successfully creates a User and Account. However, I would like to control *how* the users are created. Can I hook into the flow just before User and Account are created?

Example of things I would like to do:

- Put some logic to prevent suspicious accounts from signing up whatsoever
- Detailed control of field population. Like add a column `users.username` from the GitHub `login` property.
- Dispatching jobs, sending a notifications, ...
- Or any other thing - these are just *examples*!

All of these would require some form of a callback/hook. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Create custom adapter, copy paste content of [prisma-adapter](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/adapter-prisma/src/index.ts) then just add what you want on top of it

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own adapter with all the logic you want:

```js
/** @return { import("next-auth/adapters").Adapter } */
export default function MyAdapter(client, options = {}) {
  return {
    async createUser(user) {
      return
    },
    async getUser(id) {
      return
    },
    async getUserByEmail(email) {
      return
    },
    async getUserByAccount({ providerAccountId, provider }) {
      return
    },
    async updateUser(user) {
      return
    },
    async deleteUser(userId) {
      return
    },
    async linkAccount(account) {
      return
    },
    async unlinkAccount({ providerAccountId, provider }) {
      return
    },
    async createSession({ sessionToken, userId, expires }) {
      return
    },
    async getSessionAndUser(sessionToken) {
      return
    },
    async updateSession({ sessionToken }) {
      return
    },
    async deleteSession(sessionToken) {
      return
    },
    async createVerificationToken({ identifier, expires, token }) {
      return
    },
    async useVerificationToken({ identifier, token }) {
      return
    },
  }
}
```

## OR

You can edit [index.ts](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/adapter-prisma/src/index.ts) file in prisma adapter

For Example:

```js
...
async createUser(user) {

      if ([EVERY_THING_IS_OK])  
            p.user.create({ data })
      else
            return null
    },
...
```